# Pointer to Class Method

Tags: c++, class

I have this working code for a Console Menu Class:

The goal is to have a vector of functions which are then called when the user selects them.

I have the functions part working, but I want to be able to include class methods instead of functions, which I can't.

Header:

```
typedef int (*FunctionPointer)();

class Menu {
    string title;
    vector <string> items;
    vector <FunctionPointer> functions;
public:
    Menu(string title);
    void addMenuItem(string,FunctionPointer);
    int showMenu();
};
```

Code:

```
int Menu::showMenu() {
    //removed code to make it easier to read
    //working code to get option
    functions[option-1]();
    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int quit() {
    cout << "QUIT";
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    Menu mainMenu("Main Menu");
    Menu subMenu("Sub Menu");
    mainMenu.addMenuItem("Sub Menu", *subMenu.showMenu);
    mainMenu.addMenuItem("Quit", *quit);
    mainMenu.showMenu();
}
```

The quit function pointer works perfectly fine, but I can't seem to find a way to make the showMenu method under the Menu class to work too :\

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Member function pointers are not compatible with (free) function pointers. `&Menu::showMenu` is of type `void (Menu::*)()`. This `*subMenu.showMenu` is most likely ill-formed, and `*quit` should probably be `&quit` or just `quit`.

Comment: A direct solution to the problem would be to replace the function pointers with `std::function<void()>` and use a `bind(&Menu::showMenu, subMenu)` (or by-ref with `std::ref(subMenu)`) to create a compatible function object. But I'd rather reconsider the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showMenu` is a member function, so you'll need an extra `typedef` for a member function:

```
class Menu;

typedef int (*FunctionPointer)();
typedef int (Menu::*MemberFunctionPointer)();
//           ^^^^^^
```

Also, you'll want an extra overload for member functions:

```
void addMenuItem(string, FunctionPointer)       { }
void addMenuItem(string, MemberFunctionPointer) { }
```

Moreover, you need to pass the address of the member function:

```
mainMenu.addMenuItem("Sub Menu", &Menu::showMenu);
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How would I make a vector that accepts both typedefs?
Also how can I run that member function? I've been running the free functions solely with functions[x], being functions a functions pointers vector.

Comment: @RuiGomes You can't make a function that accepts both `typedefs`. You run the member function by calling it through an object of type `Menu`. For example: `Menu m; (m.*mem_fun)()`